# How would one use IDecorationContext api from Eclipse JFace

Tags: java, eclipse, api, swt, jface

Is there an example out there for using `IDecorationContext` for label decorations?

By the looks of it, `IDecorationContext` class seems to provide some sort of contextual decoration support, but for the life of me, I can not find any sample code using this feature...

Has anybody actually used decoration context feature and if so, what use cases did it solve?

---

**PS:** I am looking for a way to apply image decorations to object labels and depending on where the object is displayed, the base icon size varies (e.g. traditional "small" icons in table- and tree items and larger icons for content headers).

The decorations applied to the original icons should choose appropriate size decorations accordingly.

`IDecorationContext` seems to fit the bill for what I need it for, but the documentation is as sparse as one can expect from a minor feature of an open source library and there are no examples to be found.

Googling for the *"IDecorationContext"* did not reveal anything interesting either, so I turn to StackOverflow crowd wisdom in hopes next guy getting the question would be able to get their answer faster ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I did not use IDecorationContext, but you can see it used in [`org.eclipse.jface.viewers.LabelDecorator`](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/index.cgi/org.eclipse.jface/src/org/eclipse/jface/viewers/LabelDecorator.java?view=co).

It is also discussed in [this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform.pde/msg00742.html) (even if there are no answer, that can at least give you a starting point)

My current approach is to extend org.eclipse.ui.decorators using a 
ILightweightLabelDecorator to add a replace overlay to the respective 
icons:

```
public class ProjectLabelDecorator extends LabelProvider 
   implements ILightweightLabelDecorator {

   ...

   public void decorate(Object element, IDecoration decoration) {
      if (element instanceof IFolder) {
         IFolder folder = (IFolder) element;
     try {
            if (folder.getProject().hasNature("rttdt.nature")) {
                if (ProjectNature.isTestcase(folder)) {
                   IDecorationContext context = 
                      decoration.getDecorationContext();
                   if (context instanceof DecorationContext) {
                      ((DecorationContext) context).putProperty(
                         IDecoration.ENABLE_REPLACE, Boolean.TRUE);
                   }
                   decoration.addOverlay(fTestcaseOverlay,
                      IDecoration.REPLACE);
                }
         } catch (CoreException e) {
         }
      }
   }

   ...
}
```

Comment: Note to self: this appears to be my 2000th answer on SO.