# Git: Merge a Commit into a different Branch

Tags: git, github, merge, commit, git-merge

So I have 3 branches;

- `develop` - my continued development branch
- `version_1` - a release branch
- `version_2` - a release branch

I had to do a hotfix on `version_2` to reship that version, it was a 2 line change in 2 files, very small.

I wanted to apply that fix to `version_1` and `develop`.

So I;

```
git checkout version_1
git merge <commit checksum>
```

I thought a commit only contains the changes, so would only apply those.  But the merge conflicts because it tries to update all the changes between the two branches.

Is there a way to merge/move/apply ONLY the changes in a small commit to other branches?

I could just manually re-implement the hotfix on those branches, but this seems a lot of hard work, especially as more hotfixes may need to re applied and rolled out to all other branches.

```
Cheers, Will
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Merging only one or a few commits mean using [`git cherry-pick`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick)

First cancel the merge you just did: see "[Undo a Git merge?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2389423/6309)".
Then:

```
git checkout version_1
git cherry-pick <commit checksum>
```

That can apply to multiple commits or a range of commits: see "[How to cherry pick a range of commits and merge into another branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1994491/6309)".

Comment: Note to self: And that was my **10000th answer** on Stack Overflow (in 68 months), less than 6 months after the [9000th answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20683667/6309). Before that [8000th answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17569094/6309), [7000th answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14274272/6309), [6000th answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11644343/6309), [5000th answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7917396/6309), [4000th answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4953561/6309), [3000th answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3074849/6309), [2000th answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2027976/6309).

Answer (score 2):

You need to [`cherry-pick`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) those commits.

Switch to the branch where you want to add the commits:

```
git checkout develop
```

Then, `cherry-pick` the commit. First do a `git reflog` and get the `SHA-1` of the commit of the hotfix.

Then, while you are on the branch `develop`, `cherry-pick` it

```
git cherry-pick <commit SHA obtained above>
```

Perform similar actions on the other branch `version_1`.